# Opening a dynamic file in Django not in the project directory

Tags: python, django, file-io

So I am working on an app that allows users to upload CSV files and then generate graph data corresponding to their files. I have it working in development only when the files that are uploaded are sitting in the project's current working directory.

I discovered that the reason behind this is because in my `graph` view I am opening the file like so:

```
data_file = open(new_file, 'rb')
```

`Open` expects to find the file within the project directory. If I attempt to upload a file outside of that directory it throws this error:

```
Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.CSV'
```

I've read about [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) and have tried:

```
data_file = open(os.path.expanduser('~' + new_file), 'rb')
```

but without success. The above code tries to find the file in `C:/Users/test.csv`.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

## EDIT

My current attempt is now:

```
file_upload_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'Data_Files')
data_file = open(os.path.join(file_upload_dir, new_file), 'rb')
```

And the error is:

```
File b'test.CSV' does not exist
```

Data_Files is a folder within my Media folder.

Comment: Is there a `test.CSV` file in your `file_upload_dir` ???

Comment: Yes, because that is the file that is uploaded by the user that is referenced as new_file.

Answer (score 1):

You need join `~`, and file name with directory separator (`os.sep`). Using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) will do it for you.

```
data_file = open(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', new_file)), 'rb')
```

Comment: This gets me one level deeper, but I should have mentioned that new_file is just the file name received from a session rather than a full path to the file. I imagine that this will work if I give my File model a path and store that path in the session in order to pass it to the graph view and then open it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Uploaded files, as well as file generated by your application, have nothing to do in the project's directory (=> source code). You have a setting for where to store them (`settings.MEDIA_ROOT`), and you have a `models.FileField` to remember where they are stored and how to access them.